# Android custom view slow rendering with background drawable

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm trying to implement [this custom view](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/snowfall/) in my application but on some devices it renders incredibly slowly. I've narrowed down the problem to when I set the background of the parent layout to a drawable (just a png image) it causes the massive slowdown. If I set the background to a color there is no slow down.

I'm guessing it has something to do with invalidating in order to redraw the snowflakes? I've tried making an `ImageView` with the background image instead of setting `android:background` in the XML but no improvement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give some more info about the raster asset, like size? Have you tried compressing it? Also, as it may be a performance issue, have you tried looking at memory usage and maybe ensure there are no known memory leaks in your app?